# AWS S3 NodeJS Forbidden or Connection Rest

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a NodeJS application on my local machine. I am trying to set it up with Amazon S3 services, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
I am able to get signed URL, but when uploading a file AWS returns Forbidden 403 (several times it dropped connection, but stopped after I removed timeout option from CORS)

What I have done so far:

1. Created new user with fallowing policy:

   ```
   {
   "Statement": [
      {
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
           "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
       ]
     }
    ]
   }
   ```
2. Created new access key for this user
3. Updated CORS for bucket to

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
       <CORSRule>
           <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
           <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
           <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
           <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
           <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
       </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```
4. Updated bucket policy

   ```
    {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "111",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                       "AWS": "my-user-id-number"
               },
               "Action": "s3:PutObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Created call to sign url in NodeJS (with Express)

   ```
   aws.config.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
   aws.config.secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

   router.get('/sign-s3', function (req, res) {

           var s3 = new aws.S3();
           var fileName = req.query.fileName;
           var fileType = req.query.fileType;

           var s3Params = {
               Key: fileName,
               Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
               Expires: 600,
               ContentType: fileType,
               ACL: 'public-read'
           };
           s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, function (err, data) {
               if (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                   return res.end();
               }
               var returnData = {
                   signedRequest: data,
                   url: 'https://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}'
               };
               res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
               res.end();
           });
       });
   ```
6. Upload file

   ```
   $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: '/aws/sign-s3',
       params: data
   }).then(function (response) {
       var fd = new FormData();
       fd.append("file", file);
       $http({
           method: 'PUT',
           url: response.data.signedRequest,
           data: fd
       }).then(function (response) {
           defer.resolve(response);
       }, function (err) {
           defer.reject(err);
       });
   }, function (err) {
       defer.reject(err);
   });
   ```

There is one more thing I don't understand: i created a user and gave it access to s3, but I can't assign user to bucket in bucket permission. Is it missing something in access policy?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out.

First of all, I generated new access keys to make sure these are correct.
Second, I updated my upload request, to set content-type and to serialise only file, instead of FormData with file.

So the upload request looks

```
$http({
   method: 'PUT',
   url: response.data.signedRequest,
   data: file,
   headers: {'Content-type': file.type}
}).then(function (response) {
    defer.resolve(response);
  }, function (err) {
    defer.reject(err);
});
```